# How to compress php file securely

Tags: php, security, compression

I have found this code to make php file cache and compress. Below is my code.

```
<?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>
```

I've found another codes as well, which seems works well

```
<?php
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
if(extension_loaded('zlib')){
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
}
header ('content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8');
header ('cache-control: must-revalidate');
$offset = 60 * 60 * 24;
$expire = 'expires: ' . gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $offset) . ' GMT';
header ($expire);
ob_start('compress');
function compress($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}?>
```

But, when using the $_SERVER, as far as I know it will be a security hole for the site. Can anybody tell me how can I write the above codes securely, I mean not be able to do sql injection

Thanks

Comment: If you want to avoid sql injection. I suggest you start using PDO and binding variables if you're not already (along with regular sanitizing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't possibly have any SQL injection on this page, you aren't talking to a database.

However, you do not need to check the $_SERVER variable at all.

Just put `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');` at the top of your page, and you'll be fine.

It is probably better to handle gzip at a different layer (you can enable zlib compression in php.ini, or have it handled by your web server itself), but if you want to do it in php you don't have to do nearly that much work.

Comment: How does he know if the browser supports "gzip" if he doesn't check the $_SERVER variable? What if the client doesn't support "gzip"?

Comment: @Demento: The [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler) does all the negotiation.

Comment: @Gumbo: Thanks, in that case the check can be skipped of course.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does not contain SQL-statements, so you do not have to worry about SQL-injection at least in this part of the code. If you implement SQL-statements elsewhere, you must take the necessary precautions of course.

Using $_SERVER shouldn't be a problem either, as long as the PHP-implementation of "substr_count" is not vulnerable. If the HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING-Header sent by the client contains "gzip", you will perform compression, otherwise you don't. As long as you do not use the value from $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] in any other way, this seems to be save.

And as schizodactyl already said, there are better ways to handle compression.

Answer (score 0):

Sad to say, but whole question makes no sense.

1. This code isn't compressing a php file, but it's output only.
2. There is not much sense in compressing output, at least this way.
3. Using $_SERVER is not a security hole.

So, I'd suggest you to just get rid of this code, it's all unnecessary.